# Wrong data from POST request in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my simple server app in nodejs. I have a problem with handle posts from my website.

1 post = app return nothing
2 post = app return data from previous post

```
var http = require('http');
var util = require('util');

var tenitem = [];
var dataa;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.method === 'GET') {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' });
        res.end('Hello World\n');
    }

    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        var body = ''
        console.log("POST");
        req.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;
        });
        req.on('end', function () {
            console.log(body)
            dataa = body;
            http.get('http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=' + dataa, function (api) {
                var bod = '';

                api.on('data', function (chunk) {
                    bod += chunk;
                });

                api.on('end', function () {
                    console.log(bod)
                    tenitem = JSON.parse(bod);
                })
            })
        });

        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' });
        res.end(tenitem.lowest_price)
    }
}).listen(port, hostname, function () {
    console.log('Server running');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tenitem` is initialized inside an inner function and you're trying to send it back. Just move `res.end()` in that function:

```
api.on('end', function () {
    console.log(bod)
    tenitem = JSON.parse(bod);
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' });
    res.end(tenitem.lowest_price)
})
```